# I am completely new to Flask. I am trying to run a .py file in a virtual environment created in Conda

Tags: flask, anaconda, conda

But when I run the file it shows that flask could not import my python file.

I am having trouble to understand why flask shows this error. 
THis is the image of my command prompt
https://i.stack.imgur.com/soh1r.jpg

This is the link of image of my command prompt. I am using Anaconda3

//This is the code in my flask_test.py file.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```